# How to wait page to load selenium java

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium

I'm trying to find a way to make page to wait until all the elements in the page are fully updated. For example if I need to do a click which changes some value on my screen, and I want to wait until the value has been updated.

I'm searching for some generic action which I can use in many places in my program. The system is written with react, may I have any way to get to the reactjs components through java selenium? Or some other good way to make this wait happen?

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? it is hard to help without a frame of reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript executor to check entire web page has loaded. You need to add wait for 'document.readyState' to be equal to 'complete'.

This is a generic solution,for some of the elements you may need to add wait explicit wait. It depends on web application under test

To check if page has loaded, use code below

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,timeOutInSeconds);
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    @NullableDecl
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(@NullableDecl WebDriver input) {
        return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
    }
 };
wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
```

Comment: Selenium already waits for document.readyState with the default PageLoadStrategy https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/

Answer (score 0):

There is no silver bullet for waiting until the whole page has loaded with javascript frameworks like jQuery, react, AngularJS etc.

You will either have to wait until the last change in the page DOM has completed or the more proper way of waiting until the element you want to use is ready for consumption.